# iOS 11 presentViewController going behind presenting controller

Tags: ios, ios11, modalviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am having a strange issue where I am just doing a simple presenting modal view controller. `MFMailComposeViewController` to be exact. However, it is appearing behind the presenting controller and thus you can not send any email or type. You can see the "Cancel" button on the `UINavigationBar` on the mail composer, but that pops the `UIAlertController` behind the presenting controller. How has this happened? Is it an iOS 11 issue? I am also getting similar behaviour for `UIAlertController`s too.

Also, if I press send and press my button to pop up another Composer, it works as normal. It is just the first one.

Please see attached image I got from Xcode.

[image]

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[mailer setSubject:@"subject Feedback"];
[mailer setToRecipients:@[@"email address"]];
[mailer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
[self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Edit: Adding the controller for more information.

```
#import "AboutViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


@interface AboutViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@end

@implementation AboutViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"About this app";
    _contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.;
    _contentView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.;
    _contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
    _contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3., 3.);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)sendFeedbackEmail:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
            [mailer setSubject:@"Feedback"];
            [mailer setToRecipients:@[@"email@email.com"]];
            [mailer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
            [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];

        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Nope");
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Edit 2:

I believe I have found the answer. I hope this may help anyone who encounter the same issue. Thank you for all the replies, it helped me find the answer. Thank you @Mert Buran for the delegate idea. This showed me that it had a different transition delegate the first time and the one I wanted the second time.

The issue was that the navigationController pushed the new controller before dismissing a controller I had on top (a menu controller). A simple fix but because it is not evident at the start and no error logs, it was difficult to pin point.

Comment: Also I have put this on the main thread to avoid any confusion

Comment: Can you upload your project to Github?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not. But I will have to use another solution, thanks for looking

Comment: Not even the code of the one VC?

Comment: I can, it isn't much though. It is just an about page with essentially 1 method to pop open the email composer. I will add it to the question

Comment: Have you tried this code on iOS 10? Have you tried this code on a clean project?

Comment: This is not a solution but a hint for debugging the issue: you can set `mailer.transitioningDelegate` and watch who is really presenting `mailer` as [`[self presentViewController:...]` doesn't guarantee that `self` will be presenting the other view controller.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present)

Comment: What is your contentView? what is its framesize?

Comment: My contentView is the dark grey view you can see in the debug breakdown. It is the foremost view. It is constraint to the safe areas with a padding of 16

Comment: @mashdup does you app use a custom window of some sort? The MFMailComposeViewController is presented on a separate window.

Comment: I also faced the same problem where UIAlertController is not visible in iOS 11 looking for solution

Comment: Please check Edit 2. I have found a solution for me. Also Varun, the issue I had also affected the UIAlertController. The solution I had fixed it. Check the order you present previous controllers. This may help you

Comment: If `sendFeedbackEmail:` is triggered by a control then it is already on the main queue. I'd remove that call and see if it doesn't work as you'd expect

Answer (score 0):

I would try `self.definesPresentationContext = YES` in your `viewDidLoad`.  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext